# Run postgresql docker image with persistent data returns permission error

Tags: postgresql, docker, permissions, ubuntu-14.04

I've been running my docker images upon my `Vagrant` machine (the box is `ubuntu 14.04`) without any big issues. But the following error is racking my brains. I wish you people can help me.

When I run this:

`$ docker run -it -v /vagrant/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.2`

I get this error

```
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
initdb: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog": Permission denied
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
vagrant@legionat:/vagrant/sonarqube$ docker run -it -v /vagrant/postgresql/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data postgres:9.2
The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
initdb: could not create directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data/pg_xlog": Permission denied
initdb: removing contents of data directory "/var/lib/postgresql/data"
```

I've tried open all the permissions of /vagrant/postgresql without success. Maybe this is a problem of the official docker image.

EDIT:

I've just noticed that that is a lot of people facing the same problem as me: https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/issues/26

And, as someone asked about this in the comments, here it goes:

```
$ ls -l /vagrant/postgresql/data
total 0
```

Comment: What OS is your host machine? I'm assuming /vagrant is mounted into the VM from there?

Can you post the output of `ls -l /vagrant/postgresql/data` inside the VM?

Comment: @sprkysnrky edited!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just concerned about persisting the data, I would recommend using a data volume instead of a host volume.

Run `docker volume create --name pgdata`
Then connect it to your container with:
`docker run --rm --name pg -v pgdata:/var/lib/PostgreSQL/data postgres:9.2`

Even after that container is gone, you can start a new one connected to the volume and your data will be there.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure your Vagrant user has the permission to access this directory:

```
ls -ld /vagrant/postgresql/data
```

And as deinspanjer said. you can use named volume for persisting the data